# Error Running Windows EXE on Linux with Wine

Tags: linux, wine, mono-framework

**EDITS:**

> **EDIT 1:** I just ran `sudo wine prog.exe` and it seems to be doing more... so hopefully that is the solution...
>
> ---
>
> **EDIT 2:** So when I ran that command above, it actually opened wine and it said it was updating the `/root/.wine` file and it installed a few things and then quit. I ran it again and it gave me this error:
>
> ```
> 0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x309af4d, 0x3181a58, 0x3181a58) stub.
> 0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
> ```

---

**Test One**

> I installed a program on Windows 10 and copied all the files onto my Linux computer and I am trying to run the program using Wine or Mono (or both... I'm kind of new to Wine and Mono so I don't know which one I am trying to use...)
>
> When I run `wine prog.exe` I get the following error:
>
> ```
> 001b:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver >L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
> 000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
> 0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x309af4d, 0x3181a58, 0x3181a58) stub.
> 0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
> ```
>
> As I said above, I am quite new to Wine and Mono, so I don't know anything about these errors... does anyone know what is wrong? Could this error mean that I don't have all the right files copied over?

---

**Test Two**

> I just tried it with `mono prog.exe` and I get this error:
>
> ```
> Cannot open assembly 'prog.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
> ```
>
> I saw an answer to another question kind of similar to this one, but not the answer I need... but in the answer they said to compile it before running the `mono hello.exe`. This doesn't apply to me, does it? My program is already compiled... (at least I think so)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is a good chance that if this program attempts to access the Windows registry it will be incompatible with WINE.  Have you researched if this particular program is supposed to be compatible with WINE?

Comment: @Ramhound - I have not... I forgot to check that. What was the link to check that?

Comment: WINE community forums?  You didn't even tell us what the application is.  However, the fail driver call, speaks volumes about the failure.

Comment: See https://appdb.winehq.org/ for wine's compatibility list.[Chardonnay is compatible with cream sauces...]